# Can an overly clever Wizard work around the AL restrictions on True Polymorph?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, polymorph, dnd-adventurers-league

I am a level 20 Wizard whose greatest dream is to become an Ancient Topaz Dragon. I can do this easily via *True Polymorph*.

Unfortunately for me, I am an Adventurers League character, and the FAQ includes the following:

> #### True Polymorph
>
> The effects of this spell are removed at the end of the
> adventure.

Are there any methods by which I can get around the above restriction and carry over a draconic transformation between adventures?

I suspect that *Clone* and/or *Simulacrum* may work, but I am suspicious that the wording, "The effects of", is far-reaching enough to retroactively revert duplicated creature(s).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### Adventure League is built largely around trust

There is very little "fact checking" done when going to an AL table. They may look at your character sheet before the game to see if there are any glaring issues. I've never once had them ask to see the adventurer logs.

If you said to the DM, I cast "True Polymorph" the day before this session starts, they'd just make sure you have access to the spell, and let you carry on.

The alternative is that during the opening monologue you say, "I cast True Polymorph then head to bed for a long rest." Which will just disrupt the flow of everything so it's in their best interest to just let it be.

Comment: I only have admiration and respect for a DM overseeing a lv 20 AL table. I can't even fathom how tough it might be but I imagine it is daunting.

Comment: I suspect the AL rule against carry-over of True Polymorph is mainly designed for characters who *can't* cast it on themselves.  e.g. they got a party member or NPC to cast it, or they bought a scroll.  For a character that can cast it themselves, you might talk to your DM and point out that mechanically you can and will just recast it during downtime, and narratively you'd like to just have continuously been a dragon for RP purposes.  Its material components have no GP cost and aren't consumed.

Answer (score 5):

I suspect the AL rule against carry-over of True Polymorph is mainly designed for characters who *can't* cast it on themselves.  e.g. they got a party member or NPC to cast it, or they bought a scroll.

For a character that can cast it themselves, talk to your DM and point out that mechanically you can and will just (re)cast it during downtime.  And that narratively you'd like to just have continuously been a dragon for RP purposes.
Its material components have no GP cost and aren't consumed so it takes  nothing but time.

If they don't like the narrative of you having continuously been a dragon, the fallback plan is to just make the narrative match what the AL rules say it has to be, that after the end of the last adventure, your character cast True Polymorph on themself during the downtime between that adventure and this new one you're starting.

So you start this adventure in dragon form, with all your spell slots.  (And optionally without having prepared True Polymorph as one of your spells, but then you won't be able to re-up until the next day if someone dispels it, and RAW preparing a large list of spells takes significant time at the end of a long rest.  IDK if it's common to use the rules that changing out your list of prepared spells takes time based on total spell levels.)

As MivaScott says, if they really insist, at worst you can cast it and then try to get in a long rest very early in the adventure before anything happens.  If the adventure they want to run starts off in a situation where you being a dragon is a problem for their story, then your best bet is to have a talk.

This character concept of wanting to always be a dragon may require some DM buy-in, and that probably goes hand-in-hand with letting you start the adventure with this already cast during downtime.

I guess most of the time you'd be using the dragon's Change Shape ability so you can be shaped like a Medium humanoid rather than a Gargantuan dragon, so the DM doesn't need to avoid indoor spaces or something!